# CloudBackendAndroidClient error on Android at runtime

Tags: java, android, eclipse, backend

Using Mac OSX 10.8.3 and Eclipse ADT with Android SDK to follow the Google Cloud Platform tutorial (https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/getting_started). When the client app is deployed to a Nexus 4 (4.2.2), the app is started, it fails with the error "Unfortunately, CloudBackendAndroidClient has stopped." In Eclipse LogCat I see the errors as copied below. Any hints? As the tutorial mentions, this code is supposed to just work with only one line in Consts.java file being edited.

```
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.cloud.backend.android.GCMIntentService
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendAsync.<init>(CloudBackendAsync.java:71)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendMessaging.<init>(CloudBackendMessaging.java:47)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at com.google.cloud.backend.android.CloudBackendActivity.onCreate(CloudBackendActivity.java:75)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at com.google.cloud.backend.android.sample.guestbook.GuestbookActivity.onCreate(GuestbookActivity.java:60)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-03 21:20:39.225: E/AndroidRuntime(7896):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713265/error-running-google-app-engine-mobile-back-end-client), seems duplicated

Comment: I agree this seems like the same problem; The question is not as precisely presented, and the solution offered does not resolve the issue.